# How to create a membership record for a new user with django_rest_auth and django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to create an invite/acceptance workflow with Django Rest Framework and Django Rest Auth.

I have my initial account creation working just fine. Then a user creates a team, no problem. That owner now sends invites. Cool. Email's go out and the invitee get's the email with an ID for the team that they are being invited to.

Here's where I'm struggling. There is a membership model that connects a team and a member. When a user has been invited registers, I want to create that membership record.

So, where do I put that membership creation method? Is it in the `serializer` or the `view`?

Django Rest Auth `RegistrationView` calls the save method of the `RegistrationSerializer` [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/624ad01afbc86fa15b4e652406f3bdcd01f36e00/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L73). The `serializer` returns the created `user` to the view for the response.

I know I need to create the membership record AFTER the user is created otherwise there isn't a user to add to membership.

But I can't figure out where to do this?

I was thinking of creating a `create_membership` method that is fired after the `create` method is run, but that isn't working.

Something like this:

```
def create_membership(self):
    team = "6edb0a55-199a-4aae-aa40-e7313186136b"
    return Membership.objects.create(team__id=team, member=self.user)
```

Then calling it like this (this modifies the create method for RegistrationView)

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = self.perform_create(serializer)
    member = self.create_membership()
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

    return Response(self.get_response_data(user),
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    headers=headers)
```

However, that's not working either. Maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong? Maybe the membership needs to be declared on the serializer.

Would love some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I think [Django `post_save` singal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) can be used here.

Comment: That's a good idea. I can send the signal from the serializer after the user is created. Trying that out.

Comment: You don't need to **send the signal**, Django will send it for you. All you need to do is, catch the signal and create *Membership* instance